# Dynamically choose field to update in elixir ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

Its seems that the update in query expression accepts only keyword list ([escape/3 in Ecto.Query.Builder.Update](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/query/builder/update.ex#L27)). So How can I define a function to dynamically choose a column to update?

Something like this:

```
def increment_field(column_name, count) when is_atom(field) do
     from t in Example.Entity, where: field(t, ^column_name) >= 0, update: [inc: [{^column_name, 1}]]
end
```

I'v tried this but got `malformed :inc in update [{^column_name, 1}], expected a keyword list`

I also tried to use `figment/2`, and `field/2`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the examples in [`Ecto.Query.Builder.Update.escape/3`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/ecto/blob/917d50967c7f82601aca69ac7f9ba5c5c5d21796/lib/ecto/query/builder/update.ex#L7-L25) it looks like you cannot use `^` with the key, but you *can* use it before the whole keyword list, which will work for your use case.

With a model `Counter` with an integer field `counter`:

```
iex(1)> from(c in Counter, select: c.counter) |> Repo.all
[16, 2, -93]
iex(2)> field = :counter
:counter
iex(3)> from(c in Counter, update: [inc: ^[{field, 1}]]) |> Repo.update_all([])
[debug] UPDATE "counters" SET "counter" = "counter" + ? [1] OK query=2.5ms
{3, nil}
iex(4)> from(c in Counter, select: c.counter) |> Repo.all
[17, 3, -92]
```